# Extracting data from multiple tables with Cheerio

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio

I have a few html block codes with this structure:

```html
<table class='inset'>
      <tbody>
           <tr>
                <td>A</td>
                <td>10</td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>B</td>
                <td>15</td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>C</td>
                <td>20</td>
            </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>

<table class='inset'>
      <tbody>
           <tr>
                <td>A</td>
                <td>10000</td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>B</td>
                <td>1235</td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>C</td>
                <td>23320</td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>D</td>
                <td>2233320</td>
            </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Some of these `table.inset`s have more trees than this, possibly up to 6. I know what each table section means and how many each have. But I want a way to just be able to see the values under each A, B, C...

So if this was a section I knew belonged to an object `Apple` then I could say `apple.A = 10` and `apple.B = 15` and so on.

For some reason whenever I do this, I seem to get weird things like 101520 all in one text string.

If you could provide a sample on how I'd get these multiple tables' `<td>` values, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you get some weird things somehow It would be easier to help you if you show how exactly you get them. I mean your code - just add it to your question

Answer (score 0):

Usually scraping tables is done by iterating the rows separately from the columns. If you have multiple tables, then add yet a third loop over those:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // ^1.0.0-rc.12

const html = `<your HTML>`;

const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const data = [...$("table.inset")].map(e =>
  [...$(e).find("tr")].map(e =>
    [...$(e).find("td")].map(e => $(e).text())
  )
);
console.log(data);
```

Output:

```js
[
  [ [ 'A', '10' ], [ 'B', '15' ], [ 'C', '20' ] ],
  [
    [ 'A', '10000' ],
    [ 'B', '1235' ],
    [ 'C', '23320' ],
    [ 'D', '2233320' ]
  ]
]
```

The outer array contains the tables, the middle arrays contain the rows for each table, and the innermost arrays contain the cells for each row.

If you want the object structure you mentioned, you can transform the middle array into objects, treating the inner arrays as collections of key-value pairs:

```js
const data = [...$("table.inset")].map(e =>
  Object.fromEntries([...$(e).find("tr")].map(e =>
    [...$(e).find("td")].map(e => $(e).text())
  ))
);
```

Which produces:

```js
[
  { A: '10', B: '15', C: '20' },
  { A: '10000', B: '1235', C: '23320', D: '2233320' }
]
```

As before, that outmost array still represents the series of inset tables.